# How to make function that makes a variable

Tags: python-3.x

Hi I want to make a button which is going to be a function to make a variable going to be an input, but the problem how I'm going to make the function when pressed to add a variable. I'm using python 3.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a sample code I think you are trying to find this solution if not can you clarify the question.

```
def button():
   a = 4
   print("Hello I am pressed")
   return a

buttonVariable = button()
```